# ¿Desapareció la función getPaginEvent de las grillas?

Tags: genexus

Tengo un Grid UC que mantengo cada tanto y me está dando un error en la función `getPaginEvent`, la cual debiera retornar el evento `GX` correspondiente al paginado.

¿Cómo puedo resolver eso?

Comment: ¡Hola! Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y tal como está nos va a ser difícil ayudarte. ¿Tienes algo de código que mostrar, has investigado al respecto? Cualquier ampliación útil de tu pregunta será bienvenida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `grid.getPaginEvent()` fue eliminada en el Upgrade 2. Se modificó la forma en que paginan los grids, por un mecanismo más eficiente y se mejoró la interfaz, por algo más fácil de usar.

Desde Ev3 Upgrade 2 en adelante, para paginar un customer render de un grid (User Control) debes usar la siguiente función:

`grid.changeGridPage(direction)`

Donde direction puede ser `'FIRST'`, `'PREV'`, `'NEXT'` o `'LAST'`.

A diferencia de la función anterior, que devolvía el código para embeber en HTML, esta nueva función ejecutará el paginado.